# SHA1 certificate fingerprint

Tags: android, api, google-maps, sha1, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to make an app that can communicate with Google Cloud Messaging. 
 I have looked at some tutorials and read a lot of stuff, but it all skips one point. When configuring an Android Key for API Project it asks for a SHA1 certificate fingerprint.

[image]

How do I find this (I have eclipse and windows 7)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but might be interesting regardless: They are trying to get rid of SHA1 encryption because it is one of the weaker ones. You might want to prepare yourself in case they do change it.

Comment: "You can discover the SHA1 fingerprint of your developer certificate using the following command (...)". What did you not understand?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here is how to get it :
In Eclipse, if you go to Windows ->Preferences -> Android -> Build.

Comment: Will this need to be changed for release to something other than the debug keystore?

Answer (score 8):

[image]

You can get SHA1 from here using the steps and Keystore Password with be "android".

Answer (score 5):

if you are working in android (Google drive apps, Google Map apps), and you need SHA1 or MD5 then follow this step to get your SHA1 and MD5.

1. Open Eclipse
2. Windows-->Preferences-->Android-->Build (Here you will got a path to your "debug.keystore" 
   Copy this path.
3. Find out where is your jdk (like in my system "C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.6\bin "
   Now open TERMINA(cmd) and change the directory to the bin , like **c:\  cd "C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.6\bin"**
4. Now after that copy-paste this code in your terminal

> keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\pir fahim shah.android\debug.keystore" -alias
>   androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

you can change your "debug.keystore" file address here.

Some snapshot which will show my process
[image: Finding debug.keystore]

[image: Change directory to your jdk's bin]
[image: Finding out SHA1 and MD5]

Answer (score 1):

Found debug keystore file on Mac with Android Studio at `~/.android/debug.keystore`

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open Your Project
3. Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)
4. Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar, you will see List Gradle scripts of your Project)
5. Click on Your Project (Your Project Name form List (root))
6. Click on Tasks
7. Click on android
8. Double Click on signingReport (You will get SHA1 and MD5 in Run Bar)
9. Check app run console bar

Answer (score 0):

I found a very easy process to find you MD5, SHA-1 fingerprint using Android Studio.

1. Run your project
2. Go to Gradle Menu (Menu: View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle)
3. Go to 'signingReport' in Gradle window. (Your project -> Tasks -> android -> signingReport)
4. Run it. (Using double-click or Ctrl + Shift + F10)
5. In Run window you will find all info.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for generating SHA1 key for android is from android studio.

Click on Gradle on far right side

Click on refresh icon and you will see the name of the app

Click on the Tasks -> Report -> Signing Report

Find the SHA1 Key on bottom part in console

Answer (score 0):

- For **Debug Version** of SHA1 key open terminal and enter the following command.

  keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Note: If you find any error you may need to change path of your debug.keystore file(In my case it is "/.android/debug.keystore").

- For **Release Version** of SHA1 key, first you need to generate signed apk. After that you will get .jks file. Then apply the following command in terminal.

  keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/release.jks -alias ProjectName

Note: If you find any error you may need to change path of your release.keystore file(In my case it is "/.android/release.keystore").